# Coroutine launch not waiting with StandardTestDispatcher

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I’ve a ViewModel that has a `viewModelScope.launch{}` on the `init{}`. I’m trying to run a test where I set `Dispatchers.setMain(StandardTestDispatcher())` but the `launch{}` is running before I call `advanceUntilIdle()`. Why is that? Shouldn't it wait?

```
class TestViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val state = MutableStateFlow("A")

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            state.update { "B" }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class TestViewModelTest {

    private lateinit var viewModel: TestViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(StandardTestDispatcher())
        viewModel = TestViewModel()
    }

    @Test
    fun test() = runTest {
        assert(viewModel.state.value == "A") // Fails, value is "B"
        advanceUntilIdle()
        assert(viewModel.state.value == "B")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [issue opened on coroutine's GitHub](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/3880), `runTest` automatically runs all enqueued tasks. With this in mind, changing the test to this fix it:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    assert(viewModel.state.value == "A")
    runTest {
        advanceUntilIdle()
        assert(viewModel.state.value == "B")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did that automatically running all enqueued tasks get added? That didn't seem to be the case prior. Was it not?

Comment: @GregGiacovelli I don't think so, I had to do this change when upgrading the coroutines version